# How can I remove rows from a table? - "ag-grid"

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using `ag-grid` library in my Angular project. I am trying to stop certain nodes from being displayed in the table through using [doesExternalFilterPass](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/filter-external/) to achieve that.

`doesExternalFilterPass` method runs for every node in the table and should not display it if the method returns false if I understand it correctly from their documentation:

> doesExternalFilterPass is called once for each row node in the grid. If you return false, the node will be excluded from the final set.

Below is my code:

```
doesExternalFilterPass(node: any) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.columnDefs.length; i++) {
        var temp = this.columnDefs[i].headerName;

        if(node.data[temp] === 'Declined') {
            console.log('found);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs successfully, and "found" is printed to the console. The above code removes the value 'Declined' from the [Filter List](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/filter-set/) of the column but the rows that has the value 'Declined' are still shown in the table.

**How can I completely remove the rows with 'Declined' value?**

your guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me that you would want to filter out those objects from your data before even displaying it in the grid, so a simple `filter` would do if I am not misunderstanding your question:

```
this.myData = this.myData.filter(obj => obj.someProperty !== "Declined");

// then create the grid
```

Obviously change the variable and property names to yours.

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted, tried your solution and its working, thanks a lot

Comment: great, glad I could help! :)

Comment: just a question in mind, what if I want to filter them out after a button is pressed? I have to call setRowData and then updateRowData?

Comment: I'm not an expert on ag-grid, just used it once or twice, years ago :) Looking in the documentation that is what you'd want to do yes, with setRowData you can replace the data with fresh data, so it's the correct way to go :)